Getting sphinx autodoc to play nicely with typing.Annotated, Pydantic and autodoc-pydantic
I'm documenting an API schema written with Pydantic v2 using autodoc and (hopefully) autodoc-pydantic. Here is a MWE of the relevant code:
VERSIONS: sphinx 8.1.3, pydantic 2.9.2, autodoc-pydantic 2.2.0
schema.py
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    Field,
    TypeAdapter,
)
from pydantic.functional_validators import BeforeValidator
import typing as t

from typing_extensions import Annotated
from typing import List

T = t.TypeVar("T")


def create_optionally_discriminant_union(union: T, discriminator: str) -> T:
    def allow_missing_discriminator(v):
        if discriminator not in v:
            return TypeAdapter(union).validate_python(v)
        return v

    return Annotated[
        union,
        Field(discriminator=discriminator),
        BeforeValidator(allow_missing_discriminator),
    ]

class ClassA(BaseModel):
    r"""An example class"""

    discriminator1: t.Literal["A"] = "A"
    r"""Used by the API for model-type discrimination, can be ignored"""
    a: float
    r"""A float field"""

class ClassB(BaseModel):
    r"""An example class"""

    discriminator1: t.Literal["B"] = "B"
    r"""Used by the API for model-type discrimination, can be ignored"""
    a: float
    r"""A float field"""


DiscriminantUnion = create_optionally_discriminant_union(
    t.Union[ClassA, ClassB], discriminator="discriminator1"
)

class ClassC(BaseModel):
    r"""Another example class"""

    discriminating_field: DiscriminantUnion
    r"""A sub-model to represent some smaller part"""

    a: t.Optional[float]
    r"""An optional field"""

conf.py
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
    "sphinxcontrib.autodoc_pydantic",
]

intersphinx_mapping = {
    "python": ("https://docs.python.org/3", None),
}

templates_path = ["_templates"]
exclude_patterns = []

autodoc_member_order = "bysource"
add_module_names = False
autodoc_typehints = "both"

html_static_path = ["_static"]

autodoc_pydantic_model_show_json = False
autodoc_pydantic_model_show_config_summary = False
autodoc_pydantic_model_show_validator_members = False
autodoc_pydantic_model_show_validator_summary = False
autodoc_pydantic_field_list_validators = False
autodoc_pydantic_model_show_field_summary = False
autodoc_pydantic_field_show_constraints = False
autodoc_pydantic_model_signature_prefix = "class"
autodoc_pydantic_field_show_required = True
autodoc_pydantic_model_member_order = "bysource"

api.rst
Schema
----------------------
.. automodule:: schema.py
   :members:
   :inherited-members: BaseModel, str

Running sphinx-build with -n results in the following rendering as well as the following warnings
Initial Rendering
... /schema.ClassA.discriminator1:1: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: t.Literal [ref.class]
... /schema.ClassB.discriminator1:1: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: t.Literal [ref.class]
... /schema.ClassC.discriminating_field:1: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: DiscriminantUnion [ref.class]
... /schema.ClassC.a:1: WARNING: py:class reference target not found: t.Optional [ref.class]
A few things are undesirable here:

float is properly linked but Literal and Optional are not rendered correctly and raise warnings
The type of ClassC.discriminating_field shows up as DiscriminantUnion with no reference, so a user arriving at ClassC has no way of knowing that DiscriminantUnion is a union of ClassA and ClassB

It seems like what I'm doing should work based on this discussion and even this discussion, but obviously it isn't. Also, this discussion suggests I might have to get very creative to get DiscriminantUnion to show up in the rendered docs.
To get a better sense of what is going on, I also built the docs without the "sphinxcontrib.autodoc_pydantic" extension and this was the result (only showing ClassB and ClassC for clarity:
ClassB
ClassC
So it seems that Literal and Optional are now properly rendered, but only in the class signature which isn't displayed when using autodoc-pydantic (with good reason). And the class signature for ClassC does show that DiscriminantUnion is an Annotated Union, but with hyperlinks only properly rendered in the "Parameters" section.
I am hopeful these are issues with autodoc and that once resolved I can continue to use autodoc-pydantic as it does a great job of generating clean readable docs for pydantic classes
So:

How do I get type hint hyperlinks (specifically for Annotated types etc) to properly render for the class attribute docstrings (not just the class signature or parameters sections)?
Is there a way to cleanly document Annotated types and not include the additional metadata added by create_optionally_discriminant_union?

Any advice or pointing in the right direction would be helpful, as at this point I'm not sure if I've hit a bug, will need to accept some current lack of functionality, or if I'm just doing something wrong.
